# Knight's Tour Infinite loop

Tags: c, backtracking, knights-tour

I wanted to test if I understand well the backtracking, so I tried the Knight Problem. But my code doesn't seem to work. It seem to do an infinite loop, so maybe my tracking of the path is not well executed. So I wanted to know what I miss in my comprehension of the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#define N 8

int board[8][8]=  {

     -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, //1
     -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, //2
     -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, //3
     -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, //4
     -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, //5
     -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, //6
     -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, //7
     -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, //8


};

bool isSafe(int x, int y)
{
    return ( x >= 0 && x < N && y >= 0 &&
             y < N && board[x][y] == -1);
}

int SolveKnight_From_One_Point (int x,int y , int number_Moov) {

    if (number_Moov == N*N)
        return 1;

    if (isSafe(x,y)){
        board[x][y] = number_Moov;
        if (SolveKnight_From_One_Point(x-2,y+1,number_Moov+1)==1) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (SolveKnight_From_One_Point(x-2,y-1,number_Moov+1)==1) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (SolveKnight_From_One_Point(x-1,y+2,number_Moov+1)==1) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (SolveKnight_From_One_Point(x-1,y-2,number_Moov+1)==1) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (SolveKnight_From_One_Point(x+2,y-1,number_Moov+1)==1) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (SolveKnight_From_One_Point(x+2,y+1,number_Moov+1)==1) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (SolveKnight_From_One_Point(x+1,y+2,number_Moov+1)==1) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (SolveKnight_From_One_Point(x+1,y-2,number_Moov+1)==1) {
            return 1;
        }

        board[x][y] = -1;
    }

    return 0;
}



int main (){

    if (SolveKnight_From_One_Point(0,0,0)==1){
        printf(" Solution found :)\n");

    }
    printf("No solution :(\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i don't think you are initializing the `board` correctly. That may not be the real problem in your case, but just saying.

Comment: @JoeyMallone why ? i test by printing it ,it seems to work ...

Comment: For me the compiler gives a warning about missing `{` and `}` for each of the 8 rows.

Comment: I think it works, just need a vary long time. Anyway this not the way to solve the knights, there is an heuristic

Comment: @JoeyMallone even there are missing {} in the init the array is well initialized

Comment: Are you sure it is an endless loop? Your program seems to implement a brute-force algorithm. Maybe it is only running very very long to find a solution. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Brute-force_algorithms

Comment: "seem to do an infinite loop" --> No, just inefficient.  Start with `#define N 5` and works your way up.

Comment: so this is the proper way to solve this exercice ? im running this for like 10 min it is a lot  whithout finding any solution no ?

Comment: It is funny, the  Knight Problem is  the very first real program I written in my life, it was like in 1982, in fortran using punch cards ^^

Comment: @BellahsenRaphael if I well remember the heuristic is to go to the location having the less non null possibilities after

Comment: @BellahsenRaphael I am right, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Warnsdorf%27s_rule : The knight is moved so that it always proceeds to the square from which the knight will have the fewest onward moves. I remember it because it seems paradoxal

Answer (score 5):

For me your program works but need a very long time to find a solution.

Just two remarks:

It is better to initialize your array like that :

```
int board[8][8]=  {
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //1
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //2
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //3
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //4
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //5
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //6
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //7
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}  //8
};
```

And replace

```
if (SolveKnight_From_One_Point(0,0,0)==1){
    printf(" Solution found :)\n");
}
printf("No solution :(\n");
```

by

```
if (SolveKnight_From_One_Point(0,0,0)==1){
    printf(" Solution found :)\n");
}
else {
    printf("No solution :(\n");
}
```

to not always says *No solution*

---

There is an heuristic to solve the problem [Warnsdorf's rule in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Warnsdorf%27s_rule) : The knight is moved so that it always proceeds to the square from which the knight will have the fewest onward moves. When calculating the number of onward moves for each candidate square, we do not count moves that revisit any square already visited. It is, of course, possible to have two or more choices for which the number of onward moves is equal

**At the end of my answer I give a proposal using that heuristic**

---

A little change to see the progress in the search :

```
int SolveKnight_From_One_Point (int x,int y , int number_Moov) {
  static int max = 0;

  if (number_Moov > max) {
    int a,b;

    printf("%d moves\n", number_Moov);
    max = number_Moov;
    for (a = 0; a != N; ++a) {
      for (b = 0; b != N; ++b) {
        printf("%02d ", board[a][b]);
      }
      putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }

  if (number_Moov == N*N)
      return 1;
  ...
```

If I change N to be 5 the solution is found immediately :

```
1 moves
00 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

2 moves
00 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

3 moves
00 -1 02 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

4 moves
00 -1 02 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 03 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

5 moves
00 -1 02 -1 04 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 03 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

6 moves
00 -1 02 -1 04 
-1 -1 05 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 03 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

7 moves
00 -1 02 -1 04 
-1 -1 05 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 03 -1 
-1 06 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

8 moves
00 -1 02 -1 04 
07 -1 05 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 03 -1 
-1 06 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

9 moves
00 -1 02 -1 04 
07 -1 05 -1 -1 
-1 01 08 03 -1 
-1 06 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

10 moves
00 -1 02 09 04 
07 -1 05 -1 -1 
-1 01 08 03 -1 
-1 06 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

11 moves
00 -1 02 09 04 
07 -1 05 -1 -1 
-1 01 08 03 10 
-1 06 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

12 moves
00 -1 02 09 04 
07 -1 05 -1 -1 
-1 01 08 03 10 
-1 06 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 11 -1 

13 moves
00 -1 02 09 04 
07 -1 05 12 -1 
-1 01 08 03 10 
-1 06 11 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

14 moves
00 13 02 09 04 
07 -1 05 12 -1 
-1 01 08 03 10 
-1 06 11 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

15 moves
00 13 02 09 04 
07 -1 05 12 -1 
14 01 08 03 10 
-1 06 11 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

16 moves
00 13 02 09 04 
07 -1 05 12 -1 
14 01 08 03 10 
-1 06 11 -1 -1 
-1 15 -1 -1 -1 

17 moves
00 13 02 09 04 
07 -1 05 12 -1 
14 01 08 03 10 
-1 06 11 16 -1 
-1 15 -1 -1 -1 

18 moves
00 13 02 09 04 
07 -1 05 12 17 
14 01 08 03 10 
-1 06 11 16 -1 
-1 15 -1 -1 -1 

19 moves
00 17 02 09 04 
07 12 05 16 -1 
18 01 08 03 10 
13 06 11 -1 15 
-1 -1 14 -1 -1 

20 moves
00 17 02 09 04 
07 12 05 16 -1 
18 01 08 03 10 
13 06 11 -1 15 
-1 19 14 -1 -1 

21 moves
00 17 02 09 04 
07 12 05 16 -1 
18 01 08 03 10 
13 06 11 20 15 
-1 19 14 -1 -1 

22 moves
00 17 02 09 04 
07 12 05 16 21 
18 01 08 03 10 
13 06 11 20 15 
-1 19 14 -1 -1 

23 moves
00 13 02 19 04 
07 18 05 14 09 
12 01 08 03 20 
17 06 21 10 15 
-1 11 16 -1 22 

24 moves
00 11 02 19 06 
15 20 05 10 03 
12 01 14 07 18 
21 16 09 04 23 
-1 13 22 17 08 

25 moves
00 17 02 11 20 
07 12 19 16 03 
18 01 06 21 10 
13 08 23 04 15 
24 05 14 09 22 

 Solution found :)
```

With N back 8 it is immediate to do the first 60 moves, then it is more and more longer

```
1 movs
00 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

2 movs
00 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

3 movs
00 -1 02 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

4 movs
00 -1 02 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 03 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

5 movs
00 -1 02 -1 04 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 03 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

6 movs
00 -1 02 -1 04 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 03 -1 05 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

7 movs
00 -1 02 -1 04 -1 06 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 03 -1 05 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

8 movs
00 -1 02 -1 04 -1 06 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 03 -1 05 -1 07 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

9 movs
00 -1 02 -1 04 -1 06 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 08 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 03 -1 05 -1 07 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

10 movs
00 -1 02 -1 04 -1 06 09 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 08 -1 -1 
-1 01 -1 03 -1 05 -1 07 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

...    

60 movs
00 15 02 13 04 11 06 09 
-1 24 17 22 -1 08 29 -1 
16 01 14 03 12 05 10 07 
25 18 23 38 21 28 33 30 
46 55 20 27 32 37 40 35 
19 26 45 56 39 34 31 50 
54 47 58 43 52 49 36 41 
59 44 53 48 57 42 51 -1 

61 movs
00 15 02 13 04 11 06 09 
-1 24 17 22 31 08 33 60 
16 01 14 03 12 05 10 07 
25 18 23 30 21 32 59 34 
52 29 20 27 58 45 38 41 
19 26 51 44 55 40 35 46 
50 53 28 57 48 37 42 39 
-1 -1 49 54 43 56 47 36 

62 movs
00 15 02 13 04 11 06 09 
-1 24 17 22 33 08 31 -1 
16 01 14 03 12 05 10 07 
25 18 23 34 21 32 49 30 
44 59 20 27 48 29 36 53 
19 26 45 56 35 52 39 50 
58 43 60 47 28 41 54 37 
61 46 57 42 55 38 51 40 

63 movs
00 15 02 13 04 11 06 09 
-1 24 17 22 35 08 33 62 
16 01 14 03 12 05 10 07 
25 18 23 36 21 34 61 32 
56 37 20 29 60 31 52 43 
19 26 57 40 53 44 49 46 
38 55 28 59 30 47 42 51 
27 58 39 54 41 50 45 48
```

(computing not finished after 6 hours)

---

A modification of your program using the heuristic of Warnsdorf :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 8

int Board[8][8]=  {
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //1
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //2
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //3
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //4
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //5
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //6
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //7
  { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}  //8
};

typedef struct DxDy {
  int dx;
  int dy;
} DxDy;

#define NDEPLS 8

const DxDy Depls[NDEPLS] = { {-2,1}, {-2,-1}, {-1,2}, {-1,-2}, {2,-1}, {2,1}, {1,2} , {1,-2} };


int isSafe(int x, int y)
{
  return ((x >= 0) && (x < N) &&
          (y >= 0) && (y < N) && 
          (Board[x][y] == -1));
}

int nchoices(int x, int y)
{
  int r = 0;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i != NDEPLS; ++i) {
    if (isSafe(x + Depls[i].dx, y + Depls[i].dy))
      r += 1;
  }

  return r;
}

void pr()
{
  int a, b, c;

  for (a = 0; a != N; ++a) {
    for (c = 0; c != 2; c++) {
      for (b = 0; b != N; ++b)
        printf(((a ^ b) & 1) ? "********" : "        ");
      putchar('\n');
    }
    for (b = 0; b != N; ++b)
      printf(((a ^ b) & 1) ? "***%2d***" : "   %2d   ", Board[a][b]);
    putchar('\n');
    for (c = 0; c != 2; c++) {
      for (b = 0; b != N; ++b)
        printf(((a ^ b) & 1) ? "********" : "        ");
      putchar('\n');
    }
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

int SolveKnight_From_One_Point(int x, int y , int number_Moov)
{
  Board[x][y] = number_Moov;
  number_Moov += 1;

  int i, fx[NDEPLS], fy[NDEPLS], mins[NDEPLS];
  int imin = 0;
  int min = NDEPLS+1;

  for (i = 0; i != NDEPLS; ++i) {
    int nx = x + Depls[i].dx;
    int ny = y + Depls[i].dy;

    if (isSafe(nx, ny)) {
      Board[nx][ny] = number_Moov;

      if (number_Moov == (N*N - 1)) {
        puts("Done");
        pr();
        return 1;
      }

      int n = nchoices(nx, ny);

      if ((n != 0) && (n < min)) {
        mins[imin] = min = n;
        fx[imin] = nx;
        fy[imin] = ny;
        imin += 1;
      }

      Board[nx][ny] = -1;
    }
  }

  while (imin-- != 0) {
    if ((mins[imin] == min) && 
        SolveKnight_From_One_Point(fx[imin], fy[imin], number_Moov))
      return 1;
  }

  Board[x][y] = -1;

  return 0;
}



int main ()
{
  if (SolveKnight_From_One_Point(0, 0, 0))
    printf("Solution found :)\n");
  else
    printf("No solution :(\n");

  return 0;
}
```

That time a solution is found immediately :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
Done
        ********        ********        ********        ********
        ********        ********        ********        ********
    0   ***21***    2   ***17***   24   ***29***   12   ***15***
        ********        ********        ********        ********
        ********        ********        ********        ********
********        ********        ********        ********        
********        ********        ********        ********        
*** 3***   18   ***23***   28   ***13***   16   ***33***   30   
********        ********        ********        ********        
********        ********        ********        ********        
        ********        ********        ********        ********
        ********        ********        ********        ********
   22   *** 1***   20   ***25***   48   ***31***   14   ***11***
        ********        ********        ********        ********
        ********        ********        ********        ********
********        ********        ********        ********        
********        ********        ********        ********        
***19***    4   ***55***   38   ***27***   34   ***49***   32   
********        ********        ********        ********        
********        ********        ********        ********        
        ********        ********        ********        ********
        ********        ********        ********        ********
   56   ***39***   26   ***47***   60   ***53***   10   ***35***
        ********        ********        ********        ********
        ********        ********        ********        ********
********        ********        ********        ********        
********        ********        ********        ********        
*** 5***   42   ***59***   54   ***37***   46   ***63***   50   
********        ********        ********        ********        
********        ********        ********        ********        
        ********        ********        ********        ********
        ********        ********        ********        ********
   40   ***57***   44   *** 7***   52   ***61***   36   *** 9***
        ********        ********        ********        ********
        ********        ********        ********        ********
********        ********        ********        ********        
********        ********        ********        ********        
***43***    6   ***41***   58   ***45***    8   ***51***   62   
********        ********        ********        ********        
********        ********        ********        ********        

Solution found :)
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate :)

Comment: @BellahsenRaphael I edited my answer to give a modification of your program to implement the heuristic of Warnsdorf, that time a solution if found immediately, the heuristic works very well